# How to list items in an aws S3 bucket directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, sdk, aws-sdk

I have an Amazon S3 bucket by name "Project" and want to find count of files in Project/screenshots/hotels. I am only getting total files in the whole s3 using Go SDK while specifying only bucket name and an error when specifying whole path in bucket name.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/go/example_code/s3/s3_list_objects.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "os"
)

// Lists the items in the specified S3 Bucket
//
// Usage:
//    go run s3_list_objects.go BUCKET_NAME
func main() {
    bucket := "Project/screenshots/hotels"

    // Initialize a session in us-west-2 that the SDK will use to load
    // credentials from the shared credentials file ~/.aws/credentials.
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )
    var temp int64 = 1000000000
    var maxKeys *int64  
    maxKeys = &temp
    // Create S3 service client
    svc := s3.New(sess)
    // Get the list of items
    resp, err := svc.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{Bucket: aws.String(bucket),MaxKeys: maxKeys})
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to list items in bucket %q, %v", bucket, err)
    }

    for _, item := range resp.Contents {
        fmt.Println("Name:         ", *item.Key)
        fmt.Println("Last modified:", *item.LastModified)
        fmt.Println("Size:         ", *item.Size)
        fmt.Println("Storage class:", *item.StorageClass)
        fmt.Println("")
    }
    fmt.Println("Found", len(resp.Contents), "items in bucket", bucket)
    fmt.Println("")
}

func exitErrorf(msg string, args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, msg+"\n", args...)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Buckets don't have a directory structure, but they let you pretend they do by using key prefixes.

Comment: Just an FYI, max objects limit is 1000 (also the default) .. if you expect more objects you can use the automatic paginator `ListObjectsV2Pages` it takes the same input as ListObjectsV2 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjectsV2Pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rest of the "path" is not part of the bucket. You want to set the `Prefix` to `screenshots/hotels/`.
See [ListObjectV2Input doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#ListObjectsV2Input)